# Aggregate function that picks any/first/last/random value

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I run a query which looks like below

```
WITH src AS (
    ...
)
SELECT MAX(field1), array_agg(field2)
FROM src
```

I have knowledge that `field1` is the same across all rows returned from src so I really don't really care whether the aggregate function used with it is `MAX` or `MIN`. In my case `field1` is an array so I am curious if there is a more efficient way to grab any value of `field1` which doesn't include overhead of comparing it with the previously saved MIN/MAX. If there was a function to grab the first / retain the last value of `field1` that would be ideal.

Comment: How reliable is this "knowledge"? Is `field1` always the same due to the nature of the `src` CTE, due to the DB design, or due to current business rules? Personally, my first take on a piece of code will by preference make no assumptions beyond those built into the DB design (I may not test a `NOT NULL` column to make sure it's not `NULL`). If situations could change, especially without needing to change the DB structure notably, you might have 999 rows where `field1` is the same - and one where it's not. Presumably, picking the one wouldn't be ideally representative of the underlying data.

Answer (score 5):

I believe I found a more efficient SQL for what I am trying to achieve

```
WITH src AS (
    ...
)
, identical_field1 (
    SELECT field1 FROM src LIMIT 1
)
SELECT (SELECT field1 FROM identical_field1), array_agg(field2)
FROM src
```

Sub-select on `field1` is evaluated only once and only requests one single row from `src`.

I am not marking it as an answer for now 'cause someone may still suggest a more efficient way.

Comment: I am not sure that materializing yet another CTE even if it contain only single row is more efficient then just searching a maximum value in the dataset which should be scanned anyway.

Comment: @Abelisto good point. That's why I am not accepting it

Comment: Would be interested in whether this makes a noticeable change in query speed, or a notable improvement in the explain plan.

Comment: This is a good idea - and probably not less efficient than the original query - but the main source of inefficiency may be the materialization of `src`. You may get better improvements by changing the CTE to a derived table or possibly with other/different modifications. Without further details on that part of the code, I don't think we can provide more help.

Answer (score 3):

You might want the `first` aggregate provided by the [`first_last_agg` extension](https://pgxn.org/dist/first_last_agg/).

There was some discussion about an aggregate which would throw an error if any of its inputs differed, and return the common value if they were all the same.  But I don't think it was ever finished/released.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an efficient way to do this:

```
SELECT (ARRAY_AGG(field1))[1], ARRAY_AGG(field2)
FROM src
```

Just aggregate the first field with `ARRAY_AGG` and then extract the first index.

Answer (score 0):

> I have knowledge that field1 is the same across all rows returned from src so I really don't really care whether the aggregate function used with it is MAX or MIN.

If they're the same, then unless there was a performance difference I would not be writing it like this,

```
SELECT MAX(field1), array_agg(field2)
FROM src
```

But like this,

```
SELECT field1, array_agg(field2)
FROM src
GROUP BY field1;
```

Shy of that, I would go with MIN/MAX do you have any reason to believe it's not fast enough or that you could do something faster?

Comment: Sure this is an option but efficiency wise it is the same if not less efficient as it needs to compare field1 for every row to detect grouppings. I was looking for an aggregate which would, for example, grab the first value and ignore the rest, avoiding array compare operations (field1 is an array).

Comment: I imagine it's only very slightly slower and much more correct form. The first_value can be done but it also requires ordering, as in the case of *Ordered-Set Aggregates* because it requires ordering there is a lot of compare operations.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting your query without the CTE using a derived table? I imagine that speeds it up a good bit.

Comment: CTE in my case is necessary. The real reason I am trying to squeeze every bit of performance is because this SQL is sitting in a function which runs in a SELECT on a long list of rows.

Comment: A non-recursive CTE is never necessary. `WITH t AS ( qry )` vs `SELECT * FROM ( qry ) AS t`.